# How to configure multiples ips for apps in docker

Tags: java, sockets, docker, docker-compose

I have a simple java applet that has the function to communicate between a socket server (ServerSocket) and a socket client I'm trying to rotate the docker. When I give the docker-compose up command with the following docker-compose.yml can not through the client socket to find the server. How do I specify the IP of each machine through a docker-compose?

```
version: '2'

services:
  server:
    image: busybox
    networks:
      my_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.10
  app:
    image: busybox
    networks:
      my_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.11

networks:
  my_net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 172.16.238.0/24
        gateway: 172.16.238.1
      - subnet: 2001:3984:3989::/64
        gateway: 2001:3984:3989::1
```

Comment: Could you connect by hostname?

Comment: what is the issue that you face if you use the above `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: Do you mean the ```app``` can not connect to the ```server```? Please update your question for more details.